# How to implement bubble sort on an array of names / strings to sort alphabetically in C#?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

So i can't get the bubble sort algorithm working on an array of names / strings in C#, can anyone provide an example of how to do this

I already did it to some integers, but can't seem to do it with names, i just don't know how

here's the numbers code, it can sort the integers, but i can't figure out how to make this work for a list of names:

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] numbers = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Array before sorting it: ");

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number + "  ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        BubbleSort(numbers);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void BubbleSort(int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1])
                {
                    int temp = numbers[j];

                    numbers[j] = numbers[j + 1];

                    numbers[j + 1] = temp;
                }

            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine("the sorted array of numbers is: ");

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number + "  ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried that isn't working

Comment: i just posted the code for the integer sorting, could you show me how to do this for strings?

Comment: Replace `numbers[j] > numbers[j + 1]` with `strings[j].CompareTo(strings[j+1]) == -1`

Comment: OT a speedup for the best-case scenario: instead of the fixed outer loop (using `i`), use a (while-)loop that repeats until no swap was done in the previous inner loop - meaning that it now is sorted

Answer (score 0):

The logic is same, only difference is to use `CompareTo` method.

```
public static void BubbleSort(String[] arr)
{
    int length = arr.Length;
    String temp;

    for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = j + 1; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[j].CompareTo(arr[i]) > 0)
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Complexity of this code is O(N), so if your goal is to sort the array, I would suggest you to go for Quick Sort or Merge Sort (Complexity O(LogN))

Comment: that is great @PhilipMønsted

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] names = new string[10] { "Anders", "Bo", "Dorthe", "Xenia", "Zorro", "Kenneth", "Philip", "Lemmy", "Peter", "Emil" };



        void BubbleSort(string[] name)
        {
            int length = names.Length;
            string temp;

            for (int j = 0; j < length - 1; j++)
            {
                for (int i = j + 1; i < length; i++)
                {
                    if (names[j].CompareTo(names[i]) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = names[j];
                        names[j] = names[i];
                        names[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        BubbleSort(names);


        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for me, thank you everyone for making it work for me :)